# String does not retain the line feed and carriage returns in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to get the line feed and carriage returns for a textarea in Blazor, I am using `ChangeEventArgs` to update the value into a string but it doesn't seem to retain the `\r\n` which I want to change to `<br/>`.

```
    private void BodyChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        EM.Body = e.Value.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
    }
```

Is there another way to get the `\r\n` from the textarea in a Blazor razor page?

Comment: did you check if it isn’t only \n without \r? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

Comment: This is a case for breakpoint debugging.  What string to you end up with after `ToString`?

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to get the result I was after, using regex in the string replace like so:

```
EM.Body = (MarkupString)Regex.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(EM.Body), @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />").Value;
```

This changes any line feeds and carriage returns to a br tag.